# XeLaTeX Fakebold does not affect math text

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Here is a MWE of the issue.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ModernMT-Extended.otf}[
    FakeBold=1,
    SmallCapsFont=MrsEavesSmallCaps_Regular.ttf,
    BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont=ModernMTStd-BoldItalic.otf,
    Ligatures=TeX,
]

\begin{document}
    Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two vectors of $n$ real numbers. We say that $\mathbf{x}$ \textsc{dominates} or \textit{majorizes} $y$ if
        \begin{align*}
            x_{1}
                & \geq x_{2}\geq \ldots\geq x_{n}\\
            y_{1}
                & \geq y_{2}\geq \ldots\geq y_{n}\\
            x_{1}+\ldots+x_{n}
                & = y_{1}+\ldots+y_{n}\\
            x_{1}+\ldots+x_{k}
                & \geq y_{1}+\ldots+y_{k}
        \end{align*}
    for $1\leq k\leq n-1$. If $\mathbf{x}$ dominates $\mathbf{y}$ (resp. $\mathbf{y}$ is \textit{dominated by} $\mathbf{x}$), then we write $\mathbf{x}\succ\mathbf{y}$ (resp. $\mathbf{y}\prec\mathbf{x}$). For example, $(4,0,0)\succ(3,1,0)\succ(2,2,0)$. The vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ need not be monotonic because we can just sort them into monotonic vectors.
    
    We will also introduce the cyclic and symmetric polynomials and notations juxtaposed with them. The expression $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ is \textit{symmetric} whereas $x^{2}y+y^{2}z+z^{2}x$ is \textit{cyclic} but not symmetric because $y^{2}x+z^{2}y+x^{2}z\neq x^{2}y+y^{2}z+z^{2}x$. A symmetric polynomial in the variables $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ should remain same regardless of the order in which the variables are used. So $f(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ is symmetric if $f$ remains \textit{invariant} for all permutations of $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ in the expression unlike the cyclic example we just saw. For example, $xy+yz+zx$ is symmetric and so is $xyz$. But $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$ is cyclic but not symmetric. We can use the cyclic and symmetric notations to represent the expressions in a short form. Here are some demonstrations.
        \begin{align*}
            a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}
                & = \sum_{cyc}a^{2}\\
            a^{2}b+b^{2}c+c^{2}a
                & = \sum_{cyc}a^{2}b\\
            xy+yz+zx
                & = \sum_{cyc}xy
        \end{align*}
    Note that even though the expression $xy+yz+zx$ and $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ are symmetric, we do not consider them symmetric polynomial sums in this notation. A symmetric polynomial sum should have all $n!$ terms in the sum since it is symmetric on all $n!$ permutations of the variables in it. Even if there can be duplicates, the total number of terms should still remain $n!$. For this reason, this sum is often denoted by $\sum{!}$. Here are some examples.
\end{document}
```

The fonts specified are placed in the same directory.
[image: This is the output]

Comment: please provide a usable example. you need to  specify font features on the font and you have not shown any math font loading nor provided a test file (preferably with fonts in the standard tex distributions)

Comment: Ok. please check again. I added a MWE along with the output it produces.

Comment: oh you are not using opentype math fonts but classic 8bit ones, FakeBold definitely does not apply in that case

Comment: What do you expect `FakeBold=1` does? It's a ratio, so if you set it to 1 nothing happens. Are you sure that you want to apply `FakeBold` to *all* fonts? By the way, the link points to nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I fixed the link. And `FakeBold = 1` seems to fake bold the textual fonts. I will check your answer and see what comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a matching OpenType math font and specify the same boldness, I don't have the font you used but, before and after with Latin Modern

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}[
%    FakeBold=3,
    ItalicFont=lmroman10-italic.otf,
    BoldFont=lmroman10-bold.otf,
    Ligatures=TeX,
]

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[
%FakeBold=3
]
\begin{document}
    Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two vectors of $n$ real numbers. We say that $\mathbf{x}$ \textsc{dominates} or \textit{majorizes} $y$ if
        \begin{align*}
            x_{1}
                & \geq x_{2}\geq \ldots\geq x_{n}\\
            y_{1}
                & \geq y_{2}\geq \ldots\geq y_{n}\\
            x_{1}+\ldots+x_{n}
                & = y_{1}+\ldots+y_{n}\\
            x_{1}+\ldots+x_{k}
                & \geq y_{1}+\ldots+y_{k}
        \end{align*}
    for $1\leq k\leq n-1$. If $\mathbf{x}$ dominates $\mathbf{y}$ (resp. $\mathbf{y}$ is \textit{dominated by} $\mathbf{x}$), then we write $\mathbf{x}\succ\mathbf{y}$ (resp. $\mathbf{y}\prec\mathbf{x}$). For example, $(4,0,0)\succ(3,1,0)\succ(2,2,0)$. The vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ need not be monotonic because we can just sort them into monotonic vectors.
    
    We will also introduce the cyclic and symmetric polynomials and notations juxtaposed with them. The expression $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ is \textit{symmetric} whereas $x^{2}y+y^{2}z+z^{2}x$ is \textit{cyclic} but not symmetric because $y^{2}x+z^{2}y+x^{2}z\neq x^{2}y+y^{2}z+z^{2}x$. A symmetric polynomial in the variables $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ should remain same regardless of the order in which the variables are used. So $f(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ is symmetric if $f$ remains \textit{invariant} for all permutations of $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ in the expression unlike the cyclic example we just saw. For example, $xy+yz+zx$ is symmetric and so is $xyz$. But $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$ is cyclic but not symmetric. We can use the cyclic and symmetric notations to represent the expressions in a short form. Here are some demonstrations.
        \begin{align*}
            a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}
                & = \sum_{cyc}a^{2}\\
            a^{2}b+b^{2}c+c^{2}a
                & = \sum_{cyc}a^{2}b\\
            xy+yz+zx
                & = \sum_{cyc}xy
        \end{align*}
    Note that even though the expression $xy+yz+zx$ and $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ are symmetric, we do not consider them symmetric polynomial sums in this notation. A symmetric polynomial sum should have all $n!$ terms in the sum since it is symmetric on all $n!$ permutations of the variables in it. Even if there can be duplicates, the total number of terms should still remain $n!$. For this reason, this sum is often denoted by $\sum{!}$. Here are some examples.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Many thanks.